# How to start multiple instances (or seperate sets) of Sticky Notes in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-instances, sticky-notes

I want to have different sets of Sticky Notes in Windows 7 and I think could be achieved by starting multiple instances of Sticky Notes. Can this be done in Windows 7?

Ultimately, I'd like to have serveral instances of Sticky Notes on the taskbar that I can open up seperately from each other. That way I can categorize my sticky notes and only the ones from unique categories (individual instances) will be visible to me.

Comment: Pressing Shift + clicking on an application in Windows 7 will open another instance if the application supports multiple instances. Sticky Notes does not support shift + clicking to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can not be done with the Sticky Notes utility that comes with Windows 7. That utility is hard coded to look for only one sticky notes file in a certain APPDATA location. So even if you could start multiple copies of it, it will open the same file.

The only way you can have different sets of sticky notes with Windows utility is to switch to different userid in Windows temporarily. This way, each login will have its own sticky notes. But that solution is inconvenient.

Otherwise, you need to look for third party Sticky Notes applications that support having multiple sets of sticky notes that you can switch between.

Comment: My final solution was using Trello instead.